# Inequality for $C^1$ function: $|f(x)|^2 \le \frac{1}{2}\tanh \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Prove for $f\in C^{1}[0,1]$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, the following inequality:

$$|f(x)|^2 \le \left(\frac{1}{2}\tanh \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\int_0^1 (|f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2)\,dx\right)$$

This is Problem $4.157$ from [Problems in Mathematical Analysis](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cdG2LrnoNSEC&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=problems+in+mathematical+analysis+biler+witkowski&source=bl&ots=p6--6Y34CL&sig=6JmPdd2bqUJfHVnENZ25uWNcBik&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ok6lVOm7E5KLuwSZmIK4Aw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=problems%20in%20mathematical%20analysis%20biler%20witkowski&f=false).

Comment: Are there any hints or other context around this problem?

Comment: @SimonS Most of the problems in the book has hints or references in the end, unfortunately not this one.

Comment: This cannot be correct as the right hand side is never larger than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @HansEngler can you expand on your comment as an answer ? It is not immediate to me. Thank you :)

Comment: @sciona - maybe I misread the inequality. Is $\tanh \frac{1}{2}$ just a numerical factor?

Comment: @HansEngler yes $\frac{1}{2}\tanh \frac{1}{2}$ is a numerical factor. (I see why there can be ambiguity here). Sorry I'll edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We may assume that $f(x)$ has the following expansion:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_n \sin(2\pi n x) \tag{1} $$
from which it follows that:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_n^2, \tag{2}$$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f'(x)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}4\pi^2 n^2 c_n^2. \tag{3}$$
Obviously:
$$ |f(x)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|c_n|=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\pi^2 n^2}}\left(|c_n|\sqrt{1+4\pi^2 n^2}\right),\tag{4} $$
so, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$|f(x)|^2 \leq 2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+4\pi^2 n^2}\right)\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2+f'(x)^2\,dx\right)\tag{5}$$
leading to:
$$|f(x)|^2 \leq \left(-1+\frac{1}{2}\coth\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2+f'(x)^2\,dx\right).\tag{6}$$
The constant so found is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}\tanh\frac{1}{2}$: probably the original proof was designed by expanding $f$ with respect to a different base of $L^2([0,1])\cap\{f:f(0)=f(1)=0\}$.

Comment: @sciona: This is a form of the Stone-Weierstrass density theorems.

Comment: The function $f$ is zero at the border not necessarily odd. In other words there is a factor of $2$ too much in (1). It seems that repeating your argument your constant is 2$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2 \pi^2} = \frac{2}{e^2-1}> \tanh(1/2)/2$

Answer (score 5):

Since, $f(0) = f(1) = 0$,

We have, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2\,dx = \int_0^1|f(x) - f'(x)|^2\,dx$

Since, $\displaystyle e^{-x}f(x) = \int_0^x (f'(t) - f(t))e^{-t}\,dt$ using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality we get:

$$e^{-2x}f^2(x) \le \frac{1-e^{-2x}}{2}\int_0^x|f'(t) - f(t)|^2\,dt$$

and, similarly: $$e^{-2(1-x)}f^2(x) \le \frac{1-e^{-2(1-x)}}{2}\int_x^1|f'(t) - f(t)|^2\,dt$$

Combining the two inequalities we get:

$\displaystyle \begin{align} (e^{x}\operatorname{cosech} x + e^{1-x}\operatorname{cosech} (1-x))f^2(x) &\le \int_0^1 |f'(t) - f^2(t)|^2\,dt \\&= \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2\,dx \end{align}$

Now, $\displaystyle \min\limits_{x \in [0,1]} (e^{x}\operatorname{cosech} x + e^{1-x}\operatorname{cosech} (1-x)) = 2\coth \frac{1}{2}$

Thus, $$|f(x)|^2 \le \left(\frac{1}{2}\tanh \frac{1}{2}\right)\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2+|f'(x)|^2\,dx$$

*Note:* As @Jack D'Aurizio mentions, the inequality is not sharp in this form. However problem statement says otherwise (referring to the problem statement in the book) and asks to prove further that the constant above cannot be improved.

Answer (score 4):

The following is just heuristics, but indicates that ${1\over2}\tanh{1\over2}$ is the best constant, and that there is some error in Jack d'Aurizios calculations.

On account of symmetry we have to minimize
$$J:=\int_0^{1/2}\bigl(f^2(t)+f'^2(t)\bigr)\>dt$$
under the constraints $f(0)=0$, $f\bigl({1\over2}\bigr)=c>0$. Let $f$ be the minimizing function and consider a variation $t\mapsto \epsilon u(t)$ of $f$ with $u(0)=u\bigl({1\over2}\bigr)=0$. We have to look at
$$J_\epsilon:=\int_0^{1/2}\bigl((f(t)+\epsilon u(t))^2+(f'(t)+\epsilon u'(t))^2\bigr)\>dt$$
and have to ensure that
$$\eqalign{{d\over d\epsilon} J_\epsilon\biggr|_{\epsilon=0}&=2\int_0^{1/2}\bigl(f(t)u(t)+f'(t)u'(t)\bigr)\>dt\cr&=2\int_0^{1/2}\bigl(f(t)-f''(t)\bigr)u(t)\>dt\cr  &=0\ ,\cr}$$
and this for any admissible $u$. It follows that the minimizing function $f$ satisfies the differential equation $f-f''=0$, and together with $f(0)=0$ we obtain $f(t)=\sinh t$, up to a scalar multiple. Computing $$\lambda:={f^2\bigl({1\over2}\bigr)\over 2J(f)}$$for this $f$ results in $\lambda={1\over2}\tanh{1\over2}\doteq0.231059$.